# Solenoid inductance with ferromagnetic core dependence on coil distribution

Tags: inductance

If I have a long thin solenoid with an iron core, to lowest order, does the distribution of coils along the length of the core matter in calculating the inductance?

As an example:  Say I have a 30cm long coil, 1cm in diameter.  If I measure the inductance with a core of length 30cm or alternatively, if I replace it with a 60cm long core, do I measure an inductance that is different by a factor-of-two?
(cores assumed axially centered on the coil)

Answer (score 0):

No simple answer but here is an empirical result as to what happens to the inductance of a coil on a ferrite rod with $\mu_r=125$ as quoted from Demaw:"FERROMAGNETIC-CORE DESIGN AND APPLICATION HANDBOOK", pp40-47

[image]